# List of list, compare the last item with python

Tags: python, list

I need to compare the elements of a list of list. My code is for two items inside of the list of list but when I have more than two I don't know how proceed.
My inputs have the same len ever. And I need to compare `d[][:1]` and if it is repeated check the `d[][:-1]` and print the `d[]` with the less `d[][:-1]`

The print I need: `d = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 4], [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]`

Code:

```
d = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
     [3, 2, 4, 2, 5],
     [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]

if d[0][:-1] == d[1][:-1]:  
    if d[0][-1] < d[1][-1]:  
        d.remove(d[1])  
    else:
        d.remove(d[0])

>>> print d
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4], [3, 2, 4, 2, 5], [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]
```

Edited:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

d = [['4027221', 'MX', '0.4', 3], 
     ['4027221', 'MX', '30', 1], 
     ['4027222', 'MX', '0.4', 3], 
     ['4027222', 'MX', '30', 1]]


d.sort()
d = [min(g, key=lambda s: s[-2]) for _, g in groupby(d, key=lambda s: s[:-2])]
[['4027221', 'MX', '0.4', 3], ['4027222', 'MX', '0.4', 3]]
```

Comment: It'd help if you explained the logic of how your input becomes your desired output in words.

Comment: What do you want, the two smallest items (where comparison is by last element)?

Comment: I edited the ask. @JonClements

Comment: So for identical first elements, you want the list that has the lowest last element - is that correct?

Comment: What does `print the d[] with the less d[][:-1]` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the list by all but the last item first, and then sort the sub-lists by the last item with `min`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
d = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
     [3, 2, 4, 2, 5],
     [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]
print([min(g, key=itemgetter(-1)) for _, g in groupby(d, key=lambda s: s[:-1])])
```

This outputs:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 4], [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks. If I need my output in a variable, How can I add it?

Comment: Worth noting this solution requires your input to be sorted.

Comment: @MartinBouhier You can simply assign the list to a variable instead of printing it, e.g. `d = [min(g, key=itemgetter(-1)) for _, g in groupby(d, key=lambda s: s[:-1])]`.

Comment: I have a last question, if some items are str it is not working. How can I do for that?

Comment: @MartinBouhier You can convert the strings to integers first before comparing them: `[min(g, key=lambda s: int(s[-1])) for _, g in groupby(d, key=lambda s: s[:-1])]`

Comment: The problem is I have names on some items... So I can't change it

Comment: @MartinBouhier Are names meant to be compared to each other and are in the last items as well?

Comment: Yes for example the first item of my list of list maybe: `['martin', 2, 'pedro', 4, 5]`so i need to take into account the str and int in the form!

Comment: @MartinBouhier I see. The code should work then. What kind of error or misbehavior are you seeing?

Comment: @MartinBouhier In your example, all four sublists in the list have different first items, so naturally the result would include all four sublists. Were you expecting something different?

Comment: I just edited, my apologies! I hope: `[['4027221', 'MX', '0.4', 1], ['4027222', 'MX', '0.4', 1]]`

Comment: @MartinBouhier I see. In your example code, you're using an index of `-2`, which means the second from the last item rather the last item. If you wish to use the last item for comparison you should use index `-1` instead. Edit: Not sure why `max` is what you want now though.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood well what you want, this should do the trick:

```
d = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
     [3, 2, 4, 2, 5],
     [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]


mins = {}
for a_list in d:
    list_key = ','.join(map(str, a_list[:-1]))
    list_orderer = a_list[-1]
    if list_key not in mins or mins[list_key] > list_orderer:
        mins[list_key] = a_list

print(sorted(mins.values()))  # [[1, 2, 3, 4, 4], [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]
```

It works in Python 2 and 3, it does not require the input to be sorted and it does not require any dependency (which is not a real argument).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary, taking advantage of the fact that, as you iterate, only the last value will be attached to any given key. The solution does not require sorting.

```
d2 = {tuple(key): val for *key, val in d}
res = [list(k) + [v] for k, v in d2.items()]

print(res)

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
 [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]
```

Note tuple conversion is required since lists are not hashable, so they cannot be used as dictionary keys.

**Edit**: as @JonClements suggests, you can write this more simply as:

```
res = list({tuple(el[:-1]): el for el in d}.values())
```

Comment: note that it is specific to Python 3+ version which implement extended unpacking

Comment: Assuming they're already in sorted order (the assumption this answer makes) and sticking with the using a `dict` to retain the last entry then it's a little simpler to use: `res = list({el[0]: el for el in d}.values())`

Comment: @JonClements, Thanks, I think you can adapt this trivially to consider `el[:-1]` instead of `el[0]`.

Comment: Not sure why a tuple's needed there... `[:-1]` is going to be a list with at most one element - might as well just make it `[-1]` and be done with the `tuple` conversion... Also - I probably read the Q wrong, but thought the grouping key was supposed to be the first element... but I see it's probably not :)

Comment: For any given row, `el[:-1]` will have 4 elements, no?

Comment: Oh.... my bad... yes... sorry... tired eyes... obvious now they're using everything except the last item as a group key... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too:

```
d = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
     [3, 2, 4, 2, 5],
     [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]

sublists = list(set(tuple(i[:-1]) for i in d))
mins = [min([elem for elem in d if elem[:-1]==list(s)])for s in sublists]

print(mins)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 2, 4, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Scaling up [blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51878007/6775799). For bigger data and skipping the need to sort.

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5']

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=cols)

ndf = df.groupby(cols[:-1], as_index=False).min()

out = ndf.values.tolist()

print(out)

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 4], [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]]
```